# How Can I simplify this nested loop in ES6?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to simplify this nested loop? I've been pushing the values in an array

```
for (let i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
    let steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (let j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
      let nextSegment = steps[j].path;
      for (let k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
        const latLang: ILatLng = {
          lng: nextSegment[k].lng(),
          lat: nextSegment[k].lat()
        };
        points.push(latLang);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: See a for..push? Think a map!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce that by using `map` and `reduce` and some spread operator from ES6

```
const points = legs.reduce((acc1, l) => {
    return [...acc1, ...l.steps.reduce((acc2, s) => {
      return [...acc2, ...s.path.map(p => ({lng: p.lng(), lat: p.lat()}))];
    },[])];
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

An another solution, using callback functions:

```
legs.forEach(leg => {
   leg.steps.forEach(step => {
      step.path.forEach(p => {
         points.push({lng: p.lng(), lat: p.lat()})
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var finalResult = Array2.filter(function(arr){ return Array1.includes(arr.value); });
```

Comment: Just a Tip: in ES6 always try to use `=>` arrow function instead of named function